# how to show particular category products on home page when clicked on it with magento?

Tags: magento

I have to show five category's products on home page.When I clicked on a particular category,the products of that particular category will show only in home page.When i clicked on any other category,then that particular category products will show on home page.
For that I added this code below in `Admin->Cms->Home Page->Content` i.e.,

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/new-arrival.phtml"}}

{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="5" template="catalog/product/featured-product.phtml"}}

{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/specials-product.phtml"}}

 {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="6" template="catalog/product/bestseller-product.phtml"}}

 {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/mostviewed-product.phtml"}}
```

I also made five different pages in `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/catalog/product/`

But all five category products are showing on home page but i want when i clicked on a particular category then that appropriate category products will be shown on Home page.Design of Home Page is of `1 column`.
If anyone knows this, please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

just create one product listing page and add below code in it.

```
  $_currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()); 

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->addCategoryFilter($_currentCategory);
```

it will give all the current category product.

Comment: I have already made 5 different pages for showing 5 different category products......so i am not getting u.can u please elaborate

Comment: so basically you want that when on one category customer click it will reflect on all category product that is present on homepage?

Comment: yes when i clicked on a category,it will show only the products of that category